# Using sys.exit() with app.exec_ in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

Can anyone explain the relative merits of using `sys.exit(app.exec_())` rather than the simpler `app.exec_()` to start a GUI in PyQt?

I am new to PyQt and have seen both examples.

Answer (score 17):

When Unix-style applications exit, [they return a number to their parent process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) called a 'status code' or 'exit status'. `0` is used to indicate success; anything non-zero is a failure. (There's been some attempt to [standardise the meaning of error codes](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/klibc/usr/include/sysexits.h), but it's still generally left up to each program.)

[`app.exec_()` runs your main loop, and returns a status code when it exits](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#exec). `sys.exit(n)` quits your application and returns `n` to the parent process (normally your shell). So the difference is, the longer version passes on the status code when your program exits. It's better to use `sys.exit(app.exec_())` because then other parts of the system can detect when your program exited due to an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the program terminates immediately when the user closes the application window, use sys.exit(app.exec_()). If you want to perform additional actions after the event loop has finished, use app.exec_() and include the necessary code after it. If you are writing a standalone application that is not intended to be used as a library or module, it is common practice to include sys.exit(app.exec_()) to ensure that the program terminates cleanly. However, if you are writing a library or module that may be imported by other scripts, you should avoid using sys.exit() because it will terminate the entire Python interpreter, which could cause problems for other running scripts.