# sys.exit(app.exec_()) PyQT Python - why the app.exec_() is passed as an argument?

Tags: python, pyqt

New to PyQt. Can someone please explain to me why we do this:

```
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

instead of:

```
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

I've tried and both work. And Question 2: I thought that sys.exit(n) uses an argument n as an exit status. How come in the case of  sys.exit(app.exec_()), the app.exec_() is executed? Do arguments in sys.exit() get executed prior to the system terminating the app? I guess maybe I'm confused as to the "order of events" in this case. Can someone clarify this for me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075954/using-sys-exit-with-app-exec-in-pyqt

Comment: Thanks, it answers the first part. I read that post. But what about the second part? does it mean that anything passed to sys.exit() as an argument is executed prior to the exit? What's the order or events there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to answer your question but is a little confusing, so I will attempt to reword a bit. [Using sys.exit() with app.exec_ in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075954/using-sys-exit-with-app-exec-in-pyqt)

`app.exec_()` returns either `0` for success or an error message if it crashed

`sys.exit(n)` returns the value `n` to the parent process (normally your shell)

So if you call them separately and the `app.exec_()` crashes, the shell never receives the error code.

So answering your "Question 2" specifically, yes, the internal function is called first.

This would yield the same result:

```
status = app.exec_()
sys.exit(status)
```

Comment: @Michael you can accept as answer if it solves your question. Thanks!

Comment: So helpful, thanks! The other explanation was confusing. Thanks again